# Evitar que los elementos agregados en array de javascript no se borren al volver a cargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

En la primer carga de la pagina tengo una `tabla` con todos los libros disponibles junto a un `boton` agregar a carrito, y un `formulario` que le permite al usuario hacer una búsqueda de un libro(lo puede buscar por nombre de libro, por autor y por categoría). 
Al pulsar el`botón` agregar a carrito llamo a una función llamada pushData de `javascript`. Esta función guarda los idLibro en un `array` de `javascript`.(funciona perfectamente). 
El problema esta en que si hago otra búsqueda de un libro, al recargarse la pagina los elementos que tenia en el array se borran. Entonces como puedo evitar que esos elementos que estaban no se borren al recargarse la pagina?

aca el `.cshtml`

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>

<p id="pText">hola</p>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="color:red">
                        No Match any document
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {

                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="hidden" name="inputText" id="inputText" value="@item.IdLibro" />
                        @Html.ActionLink("Mostrar", "MostrarLibro", "Usser", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                        <button onclick="pushData();" class="btn btn-info">Agregar a carrito</button>
                    </th>
                    <th>@item.IdLibro</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">@item.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@autor.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@category.Nombre</th>
                    <th class="col-md-3"><textarea rows="4" cols="40" readonly>@item.Descripcion</textarea></th>
                    <th>@item.Precio</th>
                    <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

y aca la función de `javascript`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //creo el array
    var myArr = [];

    function pushData(idLibro) {

        myArr.push(idLibro);

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el array
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado! con `sessionStorage` en la función`javaScript`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //declaro una varible json para obtener el array "myArr" que guarde en la función pushData
    var json = sessionStorage.getItem("array");
    //creo el array
    var myArr = [];

    if (json != null) {
        myArr = JSON.parse(json);
        show(myArr)
    }


    function pushData(idLibro) {
        myArr.push(idLibro);
        //aca guardo el array "myArr" utilizando sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("array", JSON.stringify(myArr));
        show(myArr)
    }

//funcion que muestra los elementos que tengo en el array "myArr" en una etiqueta <p>
    function show(array) {

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + array[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el contenido del array en la etiqueta <p id="pText"></p>
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar tu arreglo en el local storage

```
 window.localStorage.setItem('array', valor);
```

Y para recuperarlo

```
window.localStorage.getItem('array')
```

Se me paso por alto que solo guarda texto el local storage para guardar un array seria algo asi

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="pushData()">Agregar</button>
    <p id="pText"></p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
       //creo el array
var json = localStorage.getItem("array");
var myArr = [];

if (json != null) { 
    myArr = JSON.parse(json);
    show(myArr)
}


function pushData(idLibro) {
    idLibro = "hola"; //Dato de ejemplo borrar
    myArr.push(idLibro);
    localStorage.setItem("array", JSON.stringify(myArr));
    show(myArr)
}


function show(array){

    var pval = "";

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        pval = pval + array[i] + "<br/>";
    }

    //muestro el array
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorge Luis!, nunca use esto del localStorage, donde tengo que poner lo que decís en mi código?

Comment: Hola aquí puedes encontrar la documentación para manejo de persistencia de datos usando [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API)

Comment: Hola, Después de que llenas tu array, pones window.localStorage.setItem('array', tuarray); y con esto se guarda localmente

Comment: o sea window.localStorage.setItem('array', tuarray); iría adentro de la función de javascript?

Comment: sip, o puedes guardar directamente el valir de pval

Comment: cuando quiero recuperarlo me dice que el nombre 'window' no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: trata quitando  el. window como en el ejemplo que ya puse

Comment: Actualice la respuesta modifique un poquito tu código

Comment: Gracias Jorge Luis, igualmente la función "show" no esta funcionando, hago click en el botón donde me acciona la función pushData, pero después no me esta mostrando los elementos del array en el elemento <p>. o tal vez json == null y por eso no me muestra nada.

Comment: te actualice con un ejemplo completo, lo probé y me funciono.

Comment: El idLibro = "hola"; era solo de ejemplo XD, lo se debí poner un comentario en esa parte, pero solo es para ilustrar como funciona

Comment: No me actualizaba los cambios!, si funciona, lo que si borre la linea idLibro = "hola"; de la función pushData. Ahora si quisiera que al cerrar la ventana del navegador y volver a abrirla desparaesca lo que tengo en el array, debería cambiarlo por sessionStorage no?

Comment: Si con eso debería de resultar

Comment: Gracias perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te comentaron, la mejor forma es guardar tu array en el localStorage, pero para no sobrecargar de variables del almacenamiento local, puedes mejor utilizar el session storage, para cuando se cierre la ventana o cambies de usuario(con programación aparte) puedas refrescar tu variable del almacenamiento de session.

```
let contenido = [];
sessionStorage.setItem('identificador',contenido);
let recuperar = sessionStorage.getItem('identificador');
```

Como consejo, por la naturaleza de tu proyecto, te convendría almacenar todos los datos en un array y guardarlo en formato json en el local o session Storage, asi podras tener un identificador por cada cadena json completa de todos tus datos.

Para poder guardar los datos en json primero debes convertirlos a una cadena json con stringify

```
let array = sessionStorage.getItem('identificador');
let cadenaJson = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Asi ya la puedes guardar en tu local o session storage, y si necesitas manipular el contenido como objeto lo conviertes a objeto json con JSON.parse.

Comment: Gracias @Jack por el consejo! lo que me pierde es como acoplar tus lineas de código con  mi código para que funcione. Por ejemplo tengo que poner parte de tu código en la función de javascript?, si puedes mostrarme como quedaría en mi código me seria de mucha ayuda